# Excel: Is that possible to erase names from other files using vba macro?

Tags: vba, excel

**Note** : I am a total newbie in VBA and Excel, but I know my stuff in programming. This is why I am posting this for a friend of mine.

He tried to remove all names he had in his workbook (1 workbook = 1 file, right ?), so he applied this macro he found on the web, without exactly knowing what it does :

```
Sub Del_Name()
Dim Loop As Integer
For Loop = ActiveWorkbook.Names.Count To 1 Step -1
   If MsgBox("Erase: " & ActiveWorkbook.Names(Loop).Name & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Names(Loop).Value & "?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Confirm...") = vbYes Then
      ActiveWorkbook.Names(Loop).Delete
   End If
Next
End Sub
```

Then, in his file's name manager there are names referencing to some other files, such as :

- http://randomServer:port/user/randomFolder/[file.xls]randomSheet'!$AD$6:$AF$6
- \\random\folder[anotherFile.xls]anotherSheet'!#REF!

He doesn't know where this names come from.

---

So, his concern, and my question here : is that possible that the vba macro erased names within distant files ? Is that even possible ?

I have looked hours for information about that, some posts I have read suggest this could be possible, but I am still quite confused, any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook` refers to whatever workbook happens to be active when the macro is running, so as long as your friend ran the code when the "problem" file was active, there should be no problem.  That code would only operate on the one active file, and would not affect remote files.

Comment: I assume `loop` is a translation of `boucle` - you may like to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45494843/edit) the question to make it consistent.  (I was scratching my head for a while trying to work out what the `boucle` variable was.)

Comment: FYI it's not uncommon for Excel files which have been in use for some time to contain "zombie" links left over from paste copy/paste operations.  It's a good practice to review any links periodically and prune out the bad ones.

Comment: Thank you @TimWilliams, now I know where it comes from and it finally make sense to me !
Sorry about incomplete translating, it is done now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no. it is not possible that the vba macro erased names within remote files.

all it did was to delete a list of links that were stored in the excel file.

same as if you delete a favourite link in your web browser, you are not actually changing anything on the website that link pointed to.

it is possible to use a macro to modify remote files. you must have access to the file system that contains the file and you must have "write" permission to that file. then you could open the file and update it. or run an update SQL query. plus some other ways that i cannot think of right now.